# NodeJS Puppeteer add timeout to waiting for specific request

Tags: node.js, timeout, puppeteer

Essentially I have a chunk of code that is waiting until a specific request is completed in puppeteer that looks like this:

```
page.on('response', async (response) => {
      const request = response.request();
      if (request.url().includes('specificurl.com')){
          console.log(response);
      }
});
```

However, I'd like to add a timeout of 120000ms so that if my specific request isn't found within 2 mins it throws a timeout. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```js
await Promise.race([
    new Promise((resolve, _) => {
        page.on('response', async (response) => {
            const request = response.request();
            if (request.url().includes('specificurl.com')) {
                console.log(response);
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }),
    new Promise((_, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 120000, new Error('Timeout'));
    }),
]);
```